# Android App that listens if other apps crash on device

Tags: java, android, mobile, crash-reports

Is it possible to have an App that works in the background and listens to when another app crashes on my device?
I want my app to notify my computer when it detects that the app I'm using on my device crashed or stopped. If so would what it need to listen too?

Comment: No, I do not think this is possible.

Comment: If using Cyanogenmod (and presumably rooted), look at CM Bug Reporter: https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_CMBugreport

Answer (score 1):

A very hacky way would be to write a native binary which monitored Logcat, upload the executable to your device using ADB and launch it using the shell account. Note that this is *not* an App though.

The Android shell user has enough privileges to view Logcat for all processes and perform network operations, so you could just scan Logcat for the tell-tale messages that indicate that an app has crashed, siphon out the stacktrace from Logcat and then send it over the local network to your PC.

This actually sounds like quite a cool idea. Might have a go at it building it myself :-)

Comment: Very interesting! Let me take a look at this. Haha if you manage to do it before me please let me know, I just need it for a small experiment in my research lab. I got the server on my computer working and the transfer now I just need to figure out a way for it to listen to when an App crashes...... I also know Tasker (the app) can do this but not sure HOW it does it

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to create **Samsung's Smart App Manager** . That track the crashes of all application and show notification to uninstall app or remove.

> From Android doc : By default, the system assigns each app a unique
>   Linux user ID (the ID is used only by the system and is unknown to the
>   app). The system sets permissions for all the files in an app so that
>   only the user ID assigned to that app can access them.
>
> Each process has its own virtual machine (VM), so an app's code runs
>   in isolation from other apps.
>
> By default, every app runs in its own Linux process. Android starts
>   the process when any of the app's components need to be executed, then
>   shuts down the process when it's no longer needed or when the system
>   must recover memory for other apps.

Each and every android application runs in isolation from other apps. So any app can't track the crash log of other app.

> The question is : How Samsung's Smart App Manager is doing.

I think samsung smart app only works with Samsungs devices. **Root Permission is required to perform such type of action.** Samsung's Smart App only have root permission in Samsung's devices.

If you are developing app for custom ROM or Rooted android device then you can otherwise you can't do.

Answer (score -2):

When you upload your apk in the android developer console you have any options including errors options, then when the app crashed in some device they can send a report and you will can see it in de console...

Comment: That's true, is it possible to see a crash of an app not through the Console on Android Studio but through another app? So I have one app running on my device and when it detects an error/crash/ it notifes the computer

Comment: this is for the app itself, not for other apps

Comment: @TimCastelijns yea, I was able to find that and thats why I posted this and was hoping I could find a way for other apps :/

Comment: You can try install alogcat to your device, this catch the error when one app is crashed